# Jquery animate div right after other finishes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, slide

I have 2 divs animating in from left, at the moment they both come in at the same time one under the other, though I'd like to have the second begin right after the first finishes.

Heres the code:

```
$("#flyin1").animate({
    left: $("#flyin1").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin1").width() / 2
}, 2000);

$("#flyin2").animate({
    left: $("#flyin2").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin2").width() / 2
}, 2000);
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use complete of jquery animate.

Update: hide the element on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#flyin2").hide();//hide second element
});


$("#flyin1").animate({
left: $("#flyin1").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin1").width() / 2
}, 2000,function(){
//on animation complete
$("#flyin2").show();//show second element
$("#flyin2").animate({
left: $("#flyin2").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin2").width() / 2
}, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't *everything* go in `document.ready`?

Comment: @ManofSnow: i am not sure that if he want the animation on page load or on any functionality. On page load ,yes it should be inside document ready

Comment: **+1** It was unfortunate that I was in school when you posted this, but it *is* the right answer :P

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#flyin1").animate({
    left: $("#flyin1").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin1").width() / 2
}, 2000, function() {
    $("#flyin2").animate({
        left: $("#flyin2").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin2").width() / 2
    }, 2000);
});
```

Put it under the third parameter (complete), as seen [here.](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)  You could also do it like this:

```
$("#flyin1").animate({
    left: $("#flyin1").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin1").width() / 2
}, {duration:2000}, {complete:function() {
    $("#flyin2").animate({
        left: $("#flyin2").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin2").width() / 2
    }, 2000);}
});
```

Comment: This works, awesome, but is there a way i can make the second div hidden until the first one is complete, at the moment they are both visible regardless of the animation, does this make sense?

Comment: @owen:Updated the answer below. pls check it

Comment: @owen I suggest you learn basic JQuery, or that you look at the **docs**

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function supports a total of 4 parameters. You'll notice that one of them can be a function which will be called when the animation is completed:

> `complete`
>  Type: [Function](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Function)()
>  A function to call once the animation is
>   complete.

You can use the complete callback function:

```
$("#flyin1").animate({
    left: $("#flyin1").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin1").width() / 2
}, 2000, function() {  
    $("#flyin2").animate({
        left: $("#flyin2").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin2").width() / 2
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add function parameter to animation call

```
$("#flyin1").animate({
    left: $("#flyin1").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin1").width() / 2
}, 2000, function() {
    $("#flyin2").animate({
        left: $("#flyin2").parent().width() / 2 - $("#flyin2").width() / 2
     }, 2000);
);
```